# Node and elasticSearch client - The client noticed that the server is not a supported distribution of Elasticsearch

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I'm using `@elastic/elasticsearch` version `^7.5.0` and Node 14. Everything worked fine, until I ran `yarn upgrade` which made various changes in my `yarn.lock` file and since then I'm getting the following error:

`The client noticed that the server is not a supported distribution of Elasticsearch`

I tried upgrading `@elastic/elasticsearch` to latest version `^7.14.0`, but this did not resolve the issue.

Nothing changed in AWS configuration either, what can be the cause for this error?

Please advise.

Comment: Here is the reason: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/issues/1666 It's the python client, but probably the same for all clients

Comment: I saw this post, but does this mean that for Node we need to change the client we are using? Because we rolled back to a previous revision, and it returned to work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Resolved by upgrading to `@elastic/elasticsearch` 7.13.0

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/issues/1519

Comment: This is not going to work going forward (i.e. 7.14+). See [this](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/73434). Also note that AWS ES will never go higher than 7.10.2, and you should keep client versions in synch with the backend versions, otherwise you run the risk of hitting incompatibilities. So you should upgrade to 7.10.0, not higher, and when AWS ES provides their own client, switch to it

Comment: I think the current solution is to pin point the version exactly to `@elastic/elasticsearch: 7.13.0`

Comment: @IchingChang true, that's what I did.

Comment: Getting it again when updating further

Answer (score 8):

Basically, all Elastic clients are going to be updated to not work with anything else than official Elastic versions: https://www.theregister.com/2021/08/09/elasticsearch_python_client_change/

That somehow makes sense since AWS ES (soon Opensearch) and Elasticsearch (by Elastic) are going to be completely different products, so it would make no sense to have one client to rule them all.

When taking the decision to fork the underlying engine (i.e. the elasticsearch project), one also has to fork the related clients since those clients are mainly working through APIs that will diverge anyway.

Comment: So I need to start using a different client then?

Comment: What's the exact version of your AWS ES cluster?

Comment: I think so @DavidFaizulaev, I've run into errors like
`ProductNotSupportedError: The client noticed that the server is not a supported distribution of Elasticsearch`

Comment: @glimmbo, I am also getting this same error, in my case I upgraded my midwayjs service from v2 to v3 and later getting this error, are you able to find any solution?